# How to migrate if-else expression from JasperReports 4.x to JasperReports 2.x?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to migrate ***if-else*** expression from JasperReports 4.x syntax to JasperReports 2.x syntax?

This is my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<!-- Created with iReport - A designer for JasperReports -->
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport
         name="convertString"
         columnCount="1"
         printOrder="Vertical"
         orientation="Portrait"
         pageWidth="595"
         pageHeight="842"
         columnWidth="555"
         columnSpacing="0"
         leftMargin="20"
         rightMargin="20"
         topMargin="20"
         bottomMargin="20"
         whenNoDataType="NoPages"
         isTitleNewPage="false"
         isSummaryNewPage="false">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0" />
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0" />
    <property name="ireport.y" value="6" />
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0" />
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <import value="java.util.*" />
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" />
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*" />
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*" />

    <parameter name="pd_id" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="acl" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString><![CDATA[select * from WF_PROC_DEF,acl_module
where pd_id=$P{pd_id}
and acl_module_id = $P{acl}]]></queryString>

    <field name="PD_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="PD_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="OLD_PD_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACL_MODULE_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACL_MODULE_DESC" class="java.lang.String"/>

        <background>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="79"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="17"
                        y="18"
                        width="100"
                        height="20"
                        key="textField"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{pd_id}==1 ? "External Agencies" :
$P{pd_id}==2 ? "Planning, Building & Land" :
$P{pd_id}==3 ? "Composit Forms" :$P{pd_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="20"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="0"
                        width="277"
                        height="20"
                        key="staticText"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font/>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PD_ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="277"
                        y="0"
                        width="277"
                        height="20"
                        key="staticText"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font/>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PD_NAME]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="20"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="0"
                        width="277"
                        height="20"
                        key="textField"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{PD_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="277"
                        y="0"
                        width="277"
                        height="20"
                        key="textField"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{PD_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <columnFooter>
            <band height="45"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </columnFooter>
        <pageFooter>
            <band height="54"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </pageFooter>
        <summary>
            <band height="42"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Another question:

Do you have a few brief examples or tutorials on *iReport 2.0.2*?

Comment: `how do I call parameters using ireport ` - What do you mean?

Comment: im sorry late to reply,i mean is how to calling the if else statement in ireport 2.0.2. using the parameter because it doesn't works when i have try convert from 4.1.1. i have try using if else conditon from 4.1.1 and try to convert to 2.0.2.but it doesn't works.i have update my code. Hope you can help me.

Comment: You can try this expression: <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{pd_id}.intValue()==1 ? "External Agencies" :
$P{pd_id}.intValue()==2 ? "Planning, Building & Land" :
$P{pd_id}.intValue()==3 ? "Composit Forms" : $P{pd_id}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: i'll try now.Thank you very much alex.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the if else format has changed. You can use the [ternary operator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) to accomplish your goal. Please show error output if you're getting specific problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reference. it is very useful.:)